# How to wrap span with label class in td

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to show a list of item in span with class "label" inside a :

```
<td>
    <span class="label label-default">My Item 1223</span>
    <span class="label label-default">My Item 2378</span>
    ....
    <span class="label label-default">My Item 898389 </span>
</td>
```

My issue is that those span don't wrap in my table. As you can see below:

[image]

I don't know how to proceed to make it wrap in my `<td>`.

If you have any advice about how to proceed...

Comment: question is not clear? what is the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a max-width to your td.

```
td {
    max-width:230px;
}
```

Also float your label to the left and change your display to `display:block;`

```
.label{
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

[See my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/numc6/)

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to wrap the td element, you need first to set the table layout style to fixed and then set the td word-wrap style to break word.

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

If you need to wrap you span:

```
span {
    word-wrap: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/j7a67/1/)